# How do I set GWT headless mode in testing only for Maven?

Tags: gwt, maven, headless

I'm using Maven 3.0.3, GWT 2.4 on Linux.  I want to set the GWT headless mode when running some tests (e.g. setting the -Djava.awt.headless=true).  My question is, how do I set that parameter when running my GWT tests through Maven?  I run my GWT tests by running

```
mvn clean test
```

Thanks, - Dave

Answer (score 5):

You can pass configuration parameters through the surefire plugin. Like:

```
<build>
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.14</version>
  <configuration>
    <systemPropertyVariables>
      <java.awt.headless>true</java.awt.headless>
    </systemPropertyVariables>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
...
```

Reference: http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/system-properties.html

The old version of this answer used the now deprecated "systemProperties" which you need to use for older surefire versions:

```
<build>
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.14</version>
  <configuration>
    <systemProperties>
      <java.awt.headless>true</java.awt.headless>
    </systemProperties>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
...
```

For more configuration options check out the Surefire manual page:
http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit.html

Comment: Possibly it solve the task of testing, but possibly it doesn't. Many GUI components are affected if a display device is not present/supported and throw HeadlessException. If you need to "get job done" (tests passed on server) without phisiclal display - you have to provide a virtual display for the application. Here are some details of [what components and how they are affeced by Headless mode](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/headless-136834.html)

Comment: The question was how to set the headless mode through maven and I answered that. I expect the op knows what he does when he searches for  such a specific answer.

Comment: Surefire now recommends to use `<systemPropertyVariables>`, `<systemProperties>` is deprecated. Reference: http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/system-properties.html

Answer (score 0):

If I guess correctly, you are running tests on server in unattended mode (perhaps Hudson or CruiseControl) when application can't display GUI.

There is another way to solve your problem (assume your goal is to run tests).
I use Xvfb - a X Windows System virtual framebuffer X server (kind of virtual screen).
It could be simpler is to give a screen to an application if it need it instead of learning how to force it work in headless mode. (Especially in my case of managing about 100 maven projects)

What you can do:

Make sure you have installed X window system on your PC/Server where you are running tests. Just hit Google with "install x window" if you need a hint how to do that for your linux installation.

INSTALL Xvfb

```
sudo apt-get install Xvfb
```

(for Ubuntu Linux) or

```
yum search Xvfb
```

(for CentOS, to get exact package name, then yum install ...) or whatever suit your lunux distribution

Create xvfb.hosts file with 2 lines containing "localhost" and "servername.yourcompany.com". Store it somewhere.

```
nohup Xvfb :99 -auth xvfb.hosts > xvfb.log &
```

(Or set this command to run on server startup)

Don't forget to provide environment variable for the session where your tests are running:

```
export DISPLAY=:99
```

I can't say how to do it exactly, because I don't know your computing configuration. I've set DISPLAY in CruiseControl startup scripst and for Hudson installation.

This works fine for me and I don't have to care about any kind of automatic GUI tests for all projects in my company. Hope this would help you.